# how to toggle input value on button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a `button` and an `input` field. When I click the button, I want the input field to be populated with some text. And when click the button again, I want the populated text to disappear or become `Null`.

When I checked online, I could only find links to toggle classes from elements in the list.

How do I achieve this with `jQuery`?

This is my code so far. I am able to populate the input field with the required value. But I am not able to remove the value when I click the button again.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="test-button" data-toggle="button" aria pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
    Click Me
</button>
<input type="text" name="test-input" id="test-input" value="">


<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#test-button').click(function()
    {
      $('#test-input').val("Value Populated");
    }
  )
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="test-button" data-toggle="button" aria pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
    Click Me
</button>
<input type="text" name="test-input" id="test-input" value="">


<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#test-button').click(function()
    {
      const $testInput = $('#test-input');
      if (!$('#test-input').val().length) {
        $('#test-input').val("Value Populated");
      } else {
        $('#test-input').val("");
      }
      
    }
  )
</script>
```

Comment: Posted the same time. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the value exists and remove the value if it exists.
Try it like this

```js
  $('#test-button').click(function()
    { 
    if($('#test-input').val() != "Value Populated"){
     $('#test-input').val("Value Populated");
    }else{
    $('#test-input').val("");
    }
     
      
    }
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="test-button" data-toggle="button" aria pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
    Click Me
</button>
<input type="text" name="test-input" id="test-input" value="">
```

Another option is set a data attribute to the input when the value is set.This will help you to reset even if the  input is changed

```js
 $('#test-button').click(function()
    {
      let valueSet =  $('#test-input').attr('data-set');
      if(valueSet  ==1){
        $('#test-input').attr('data-set','0').val("");
      }else{
        $('#test-input').attr('data-set','1').val("Value Populated");
      }
      
    }
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="test-button" data-toggle="button" aria pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
    Click Me
</button>
<input type="text" name="test-input" id="test-input" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if you have something as value:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test-button').on('click',function() {
    if ($('#test-input').val()) {
      $('#test-input').val("")
    } else {
      $('#test-input').val("Value Populated")
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="test-button" data-toggle="button" aria pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
    Click Me
</button>
<input type="text" name="test-input" id="test-input" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is a value in your input "test-input", if not add text otherwise remove text -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#test-button').click(function()
  {
     if ($('#test-input').val == '' || $('#test-input').val == null) {
       $('#test-input').val("Value Populated");
     } else {
       $('#test-input').val("");
     }
  }
)
</script>enter code here
```